# Why would some backup schedules work and others not?

Tags: 7, backups

I have several backup schedules set up:

- Every 15 minutes (keeping 12)
- Every 8 hours (keeping 9)
- Daily Backup (keeping 31)
- Weekly Backup (keeping 52)
- Yearly Backup (keeping 5)

The perplexing problem is that some of them seem to be working and some not, even though they're all using the default profile, and they're all enabled, and they're all being saved to the scheduled backups directory.

Here are the backups that are appearing:

```
sitename-2012-11-10T18-10-05 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 18:10 25 min  311.12 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T18-03-58 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 18:03 31 min  305.58 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T17-48-49 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 17:48 46 min  308.19 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T16-43-06 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 16:43 1 hour  303.99 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T16-43-05 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 16:43 1 hour  303.99 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T15-43-02 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 15:43 2 hours 304.01 KB  
sitename-2012-11-10T14-43-00 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 14:43 3 hours 303.99 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T13-38-00 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 13:38 4 hours 303.95 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T12-33-00 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 12:33 6 hours 303.95 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T11-28-01 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 11:28 7 hours 303.94 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T10-23-00 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 10:23 8 hours 303.95 KB 
sitename-2012-11-10T09-18-02 Sat, 11/10/2012 - 09:18 9 hours 303.94 KB
```

The fact that there are 12 (which is the number mentioned in *one* of the schedules) makes me think that perhaps the Backup & Restore module has a major bug: perhaps it assumes you'll only have one or two schedules, and my 5 overwhelmed it.

Is there any other reason for the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: You should override the name to include the schedule the schedule name so you can figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating different destinations for each schedule, the problem goes away.

Apparently Backup & Migrate simply assumes each schedule has a separate destination (although the UI gives no hint that this would be the case, and in fact gives reason to expect that there's no problem with sharing a destination).

For instance, one of my schedules is set to keep 12 copies.  Rather than keeping track of which backups belong to which schedule, it merely deletes all but the last 12 backups in the directory.

At any rate, isolating each backup allows everything to work as expected.